# Wordpress blogsite logo is different on my computer and mobile

Tags: mobile, logo

I was hoping someone could help me with an issue I'm having with my wordpress site.
the logo is different on my pc and mobile, my pc site is the correct logo but my mobile site is the same logo as the template I used for the theme. Is this a theme issue or a plugin issue maybe?
I've tried clearing browsing cache but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd guess your theme has different images for each resolution and you've only changed the desktop one. Can you check what URL each image is using? For the mobile view you can use your browser's debug tools to pretend to be mobile to see the mobile view.

Comment: But you should ask the theme authors for help if you haven't already. They'll know where this should be configured.

Comment: HI Rup

I'm not sure how to check the url on the the mobile for the image? i've found the url on my desktop though. i'm using elementor themes and editing them in elementor as well so I will see if they can help. Let me know if you have any other options to try fixing this issue.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Chrome or Edge open the developer tools from the three-dots menu, then in the top right there's [a 'Device Toolbar' button](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/) you can use to tell it to pretend to be a mobile device. You should be able to get the URL then. All browsers should support this nowadays, e.g. for Safari you need to enable the developer menu then it's the top item 'Open Page with'.

Comment: Checking the image URL though is more or less just verifying that it's a different image served though, which I'd guess it is. You can then find and update that image on disk, or through the media library in the site. I'd guess there's an Elementor way or a theme-specific way to do this too.